# How can I solve this unexpected token error?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, unexpected-token

I'm trying to make a very simple drawing app and I'm having real trouble with syntax...

I just want the user to be able to draw a line on a canvas.

```js
// paint.js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  //resizing
  //canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  //canvas.width = window.innerWidth;

  //variables
  var painting = false;

  function startPosition(e) {
    painting = true;
    draw(e);
  }

  function endPosition() {
    painting = false;
    context.beginPath();
  }

  function draw(e) {
    if (!painting) return;
    context.lineWidth = 7;
    context.lineCap = "round";
    context.strokeStyle = "green";

    context.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    context.stroke();
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  }

  //EventListeners
  canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startPosition)
  canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", endPosition);
  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
};
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>draw</title>
<link href="grove.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<h1>draw</h1>

<div class="nav">
    
        <a href="artists.html">artists</a>
        <a href="draw.html">draw and listen</a>
        <a href="store.html">store</a>

</div>
    
<div>
  <canvas id="canvas" height="480" width="640" style="border:1px solid #000000; background-color: white;">Please update your browser.</canvas>
  <!-- <script src="paint.js"></script> -->
</div>

<a class="aHome" href="index.html"><img src="img/planet-green.png" style="float:right;width:42px;height:42px;" alt="home planet"></a>

<div>

    <p style="clear: right;">© 2020</p>
    
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

There are the full HTML and js files for more context to try and solve the issue of the canvas not responding in a web page. It seems to work fine as a standalone function within stack overflow, leading me to believe the problem with with the other code...

Comment: Remove the `function` keyword from your `addEventListener` lines. You aren't defining a function there, just referencing an existing one. Ie `canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startPosition)`

Comment: Thank you, that got rid of the message! I made the indents more consistent too. Thanks for that :)

Comment: Do you see any additional issues, perhaps with the way I'm connecting the canvas element to the javascript? Now I'm not getting any errors, but the canvas remains an unresponsive white square on the page.

Comment: You've defined the 2D context as `context` but then use an undefined variable `ctx`

Comment: Alright, I fixed that, but the same issue is still there. I have a blank canvas that doesn't seem to want to be drawn on.

Comment: Please update the code in your question

Comment: Right, sorry. There's the updated code.

Comment: I made your code into a runnable snippet above and it works fine

Comment: At the end of your script ; should not exist. Don't end functions with semicolons.

Comment: @DanielTate there's no problem with that semi-colon

Comment: I can see it working within stackoverflow... but I can't get it working when I load the page on my browser to test it... I'm updating the question with more of the code to see if there's an issue elsewhere.

Comment: Try removing the `window.load` part and just run your script in an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE). Here's a working demo ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-cannon-9nff8?file=/paint.js

Comment: It's still not working, dang... I'm not sure what to do at this point.